# How to include derived property of type contained in a List

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6

I've got a data context with a list of pipelines. I want to query one pipeline containing all its properties and sub-properties. One pipeline has got a list of stages. The base stage type is abstract. In the list, there can be stages of different child types, here for example it is SpecialStage. A SpecialStage has got a property Settings of type SpecialStageSettings. I want to especially load this SpecialStageSettings object within the query.

With Entity Framework 6.x, I tried

```
var pipeline = context.Pipelines.Include(x => x.Stages).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == idOfAddedPipeline);
```

but that doesn't work completely, because the Settings property of SpecialStage type stays null.
How can I include all sub-properties and sub-sub-properties to be included in the query result?

The data model is the following:

```
    public abstract class EntityBaseModel<TKey>
    {
        public TKey Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pipeline : EntityBaseModel<string>
    {
        public List<Stage> Stages { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Stage : EntityBaseModel<string> { }

    public class SpecialStage : Stage
    {
        public SpecialStageSettings Settings { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class StageSettings : EntityBaseModel<string> { }

    public class SpecialStageSettings : StageSettings
    {
        public double Timeout { get; set; }

        public int TriggerMode { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Just looking at your code, is there a reason you dont define a StageSetting class in your abstract stage class? this way all your stage implementations can have a StageSetting class or a derived type and it will be easier to include the settings. like so `public abstract class Stage : EntityBaseModel<string> { }`

Comment: `public abstract class Stage : EntityBaseModel<string> {  public StageSettings Settings { get; set; } }`

Comment: This would be possibly also, if it works. But in this case, the child settings class (for instance SpecialStageSettings) would have to be loaded in the Stage implementations.

Comment: if you inheritance is set up right, this will be the case!

Answer (score 0):

To include Settings entity use Select and specify entity you want to load.

```
var pipeline = context.Pipelines.Include(x => x.Stages.Select(s => s.Settings)).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == idOfAddedPipeline);
```

You will have to select every entity you wish to load.